'fight tooth and nail' - Can it be used for peaceful struggles?
According to Cambridge dictionary -

fight tooth and nail:
to try very hard to get something you want:

Does this idiom suggest that there is violence  (biting, scratching)?
Can this expression be used for a nonviolent yet prolonged conflict such as the South Africa's Independence movement? Is the usage correct -
Nelson Mandela fought tooth and nail against apartheid, in South Africa..
Edit 1. (I agree with the views expressed by the respondents).
Origin : The phrase fight tooth and nail comes from the descriptive imagery of a wild beast in a fierce battle, using its teeth and nails (or claws) as weapons.

I'm not sure where you got the idea that Indian independence was non-violent from.

@DJClayworth It's an accepted fact worldwide. Mahatma Gandhi's birthday on 2nd October is celebrated by UN as International day of Non-violence. There is a famous quote attributed to Einstein about Gandhi: "Generations to come, it may well be, will scarce believe that such a man as this one ever in flesh and blood walked upon this Earth".
https://www.un.org/en/observances/non-violence-day

Prafulla Chaki was associated with the Jugantar. He carried out assassinations against British colonial officials in an attempt to secure Indian independence. He was one among very many from 1857 to 1947.

@JamesMathai There was more to Indian independence than Gandhi.

Here's a dialogue from BBC website on the idiom, which goes on to say although the idiom looks violent, it can be used for all situations.
Rob : "Really? I don’t think so. I’m going to fight tooth and nail to get them to change their mind."
Feifei: "Ooo, that sounds painful – protesting with your teeth and nails."
https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/features/the-english-we-speak/ep-190708

"Fight tooth and nail" can be used metaphorically. A political campaign, a legal battle or a game of chess can all involve fighting "tooth and nail" if they are difficult and involve trying very hard. They don't have to be physically violent. This is what the dictionary definition means.
References:

BBC Learning English
Literary devices
ABC News
English the Easy Way
Bloomberg


+1. Indeed, I've never heard it used literally.

Some evidence would be good.

@StuartF The dictionary definition is a good starting reference. I've added more.
